# Active Directory hosted on Azure VM issue related to browsing on added workstations/servers (DNS)

Tags: azure, microsoft

First of all i want to share that i don't have much experience with Microsoft Azure, Windows Servers, etc. and i want to set up working environment in the cloud only (on premise i have only workstations and network devices).

What i have now is: Availability set of 2 Domain controllers hosted on Azure VMs, Site-To-Site connection from the office to Azure VNet (working fine), DNS configuration on VNet level - custom DNS, which is the IP addresses of the domain controllers (static). I managed to join local workstation to Active Directory that is hosted on the VMs. The problem is that i have to add (manually) the DNS servers on the local network of the machine to be able to reach and join to the AD. Now the workstations joined into the domain have issues browsing internet. I am sure that it is a DNS issue, but i don't know how to solve it.

Can someone tell me where i am doing the configuration wrong?

Comment: Maybe your Azure DCs don’t have root hints in the DNS? Can you ping google.com (?) and ping 8.8.8.8 (?) .

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your comment!
They have root hints and i tried to add forwarder but you are right, i cant ping 8.8.8.8.

Comment: If you can’t ping an IP then it’s probably not DNS but rather routing.Any different path if you do tracert 8.8.8.8 from a domain joined workstation vs non-domainjoined?